# THREEjs update vertices of WireframeHelper

Tags: geometry, mesh, vertices

I have an object with a geometry whereby I can access the vertices and update their position. The corresponding object updates within the scene but the wireframe of that object does not. Any thought on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wireframe Helper use BufferGeometry and I beileve you are try to access 
object.geometry.vertices correct me if wrong.
BufferGeometry have direct attribute position to change. try suing 
new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(wireframeGeometry)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by using another approach. There is a wireframe option within THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(). That did the job;)